# Assign single task to multiple reviewers in sharepoint 2013 visual studio workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, custom-actions

**Problem**: I need to assign single task to multiple approvers. i have approver's email id in a string separated by semicolon.

**Challenge**: since we can assign single task to either a single user or SharePoint group, how can we assign it to multiple users separated by semicolon.?

Thanks in advance!.